# How to correctly set SSL in pg_hba.conf of postgreSQL-11?

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-11, pg-hba.conf

In Ubuntu 18.04.02 Server Edition with postgreSQL-11 I want to add the possibility of SSL communication between the postgreSQL server and a client.

I turned the ssl on in postgresql.conf :

sudo nano /etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf

```
ssl = on
```

and in pg_hba.conf  I added a line for ssl :

sudo nano /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS 
            METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

host    all             all             192.168.1.1/24          md5

# Only for SSL connections :
hostssl all             all                                     cert
```

But when reloading the new configuration, and restarting postgreSQL :

```
(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload
[ ok ] Reloading postgresql configuration (via systemctl):   
postgresql.service.
(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo service postgresql restart
(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled;  
vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2019-09-16 18:48:13 CEST; 6s 
ago
  Process: 3349 ExecReload=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3399 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3399 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 16 18:48:13 pc systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Sep 16 18:48:13 pc systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

I get this error:

(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo su -l postgres
postgres@pc:~$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I already tried the suggestions found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432
withour any success

When commenting the hostssl line in pg_hba.conf:

```
# Only for SSL connections :
#hostssl all             all      cert
```

The error disappears:

```
(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload
[ ok ] Reloading postgresql configuration (via systemctl):   
postgresql.service.
(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo service postgresql restart
(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled;
vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2019-09-16 18:52:37 CEST; 3s 
ago
  Process: 3455 ExecReload=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3511 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3511 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 16 18:52:37 pc systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Sep 16 18:52:37 pc systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
(base) marco@pc:~$ sudo su -l postgres
postgres@pc:~$ psql
psql (11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-1.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# help
You are using psql, the command-line interface to PostgreSQL.
Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
       \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help with psql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit
postgres=#
```

So, my question is : how to correctly set ssl in /etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf ?

SOLVED: adding the IP addresses range in pg_hba.conf:

```
hostssl all             all             192.168.1.0/24          cert
```